# CKeditor language direction

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

How Could I set ckeditor language direction to nothing like this:

```
<html dir="">
```

by default it is:

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

Where could I modify its code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution for my problem is:

```
config.contentsLangDirection = 'ui';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think u can use [this](http://docs.cksource.com/Talk%3aCKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide#Writing_direction_of_the_language) :

```
config.contentsLangDirection = 'rtl';
```

Comment: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.contentsLangDirection

Answer (score -1):

abdolsamadseif
code down success

```
RtlCkeditor();
function RtlCkeditor() {
    CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
        // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
        var dialogName = ev.data.name;
        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
        // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
        // interested in (the 'image' dialog).
        if (dialogName == 'image') {
            // Get a reference to the 'Image Info' tab.
            var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
            // Remove unnecessary widgets/elements from the 'Image Info' tab.
            infoTab.remove('browse');
            infoTab.remove('txtHSpace');
            infoTab.remove('txtVSpace');
            infoTab.remove('txtBorder');
            infoTab.remove('txtAlt');
            infoTab.remove('txtWidth');
            infoTab.remove('txtHeight');
            infoTab.remove('htmlPreview');
            infoTab.remove('cmbAlign');
            infoTab.remove('ratioLock');
        }
    });
    CKEDITOR.config.contentsLangDirection = 'rtl';

    CKEDITOR.replace('#IDElementCkeditore');
}
```

Comment: please look at [answer]. code-only answers aren't useful to the community